# Unable to send data from Stripe Webhook to Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, stripe-payments

I have made a Stripe webhook and I want to write data to Firebase when a Stripe purchase happens, and it isn't working although the payment always succeeds but the data is not sent to Firebase database.

In the following I will provide my code:

` import {
buffer
} from "micro";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

```
// <--SECURE A CONNECTION TO FIREBASE FROM THE BACKEND -->
const serviceAccount = require("../../../permissions.json");

const app = !admin.apps.length ?
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  }) :
  admin.app();

// Establish connection to stripe. Stripe initialization

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;

const fulfillOrder = async(session) => {

  console.log("FULFILL ORDER", session);
   return app
    .firestore()
    .collection("user")
    .doc(session.metadata.email)
    .collection("orders")
    .doc(session.id)
   .set({
     amount: session.amount_total / 100,
      amount_shipping: session.total_details.amount_shipping / 100,
       images: JSON.parse(session.metadata.images),
      timestamp: admin.firestore().FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
      .then(() => {
         console.log(`SUCCESS: Order ${session.id} had been added to the DB `);
      })
};

export default async(req, res) => 

  // In next js if we want to check if we have a get request or post request, etc, we do in the following way

  if (req.method === "POST") {

    const requestBuffer = await buffer(req);
    const payload = requestBuffer.toString();
    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    let event;

    // Verify that the EVENT POSTED came from Stripe

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error", err.message);
      return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${err.message}`);
    }

    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      const session = event.data.object;

      return fulfillOrder(session)
        .then(() => res.status(200))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`));
    }
  }
};

// in order to implement webhook with NEXTJS  we need to DISABLE few features in the config

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
    externalResolver: true,
  },
}; `
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the data is not sent to Firebase database"? Does your code get to the `event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);` line when you receive events? Are you seeing errors when this code is run?

Comment: If your code is not being executed at all when an event is sent out, I would check specific events in your Stripe dashboard to see if Stripe has attempted to send the webhook events and what errors it may have run in to if it did. If Stripe is sending events but your code isn't seeing them, I would check your Firebase/Google cloud config. https://dashboard.stripe.com/events/